# Lack of optimisation in OfType<TResult>()

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I was looking at the source code for `System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType<TResult>()`:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(this IEnumerable source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        return OfTypeIterator<TResult>(source);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TResult> OfTypeIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) {
        foreach (object obj in source) {
            if (obj is TResult) yield return (TResult)obj;
        }
    }
```

If `IEnumerable<TResult> typedSource = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;` results in a non-null value, and  `TResult` is a value type, then there can't be any `null` values, and therefore no need to enumerate through every value.

You can just return the source as an `IEnumerable<TResult>`

Is there any reason why they didn't design the method like this?:

```
        public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

            IEnumerable<TResult> typedSource = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
            if (typedSource != null)
            {
                if (typeof(TResult).IsValueType)
                {
                    return typedSource;
                }
            }

            return OfTypeIterator<TResult>(source);
        }
```

If the source has a huge amount of elements, it could save a lot of time by just checking to see if the source contains only value types.

**EDIT:**

I know some beginner developers haven't yet learned about value/reference types and don't know that value types can't be `null`.
I can imagine situations where a beginner developer would learn that `OfType<T>()` filters out `null` values, thinking it'd work on a list of `int`s.
For these occasions, the optimisation would benefit the programmer (though not as much as learning about value/reference types).

I got the idea from [Jon Skeet's blog](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/13/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-33-cast-and-oftype/)

Comment: I could be wrong here, but the only place this could be useful is when T (of source) == TResult. If TResult is ValueType and is same as T, why would one want to use OfType ? Not sure, how this would actually optimize the OfType method

Comment: Where did you get this implementation from? I remember there are different implementations for different frameworks. for example different between .Net Core and .NET framework

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary this is from the source code in GitHub.

Comment: @AnuViswan: It's possible that you may not know the `T` of the source at compile-time. Don't forget that this (and `Cast`) target `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. The `Cast` method *is* optimized like this.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work where `TResult` is a nullable value type - the real `OfType` method filters out null values from that as well. You could fix that fairly easily though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Jon. Didn't realize that Cast/OfType was targeting IEnumerable and not IEnumerable<T>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the people at Microsoft who implemented that method can tell you for sure why it was implemented the way it was. However…

It's important to note that *your* proposed alternative doesn't work in very many interesting scenarios. It's very limited in when it would work, as compared to the scenarios where `OfType<T>()` might be called.

Indeed, it *only* works in the scenarios where the caller shouldn't be calling `OfType<T>()` in the first place. After all, if the object is actually already the type `IEnumerable<TResult>`, it's pointless to *filter* the source by type. Callers should already know enough about the source's actual type to know whether such filtering is really needed or not. And they certainly shouldn't be calling `OfType<T>()` for its side-effect of removing `null` values.

So, why introduce an "optimization" that only optimizes code that should never have been written in the first place? That'd be pretty much contrary to the usual guidelines for optimization. One of the first rules is to focus on the *common* case. Optimizing the uncommon case is often a waste of code, particularly in a library, and that's especially true when the particular uncommon case in question involves *bad* code.

Comment: Why shouldn't developers use OfType() to get rid of null values? What's the best way to filter them out?

Comment: _"Why shouldn't developers use OfType() to get rid of null values?"_ -- because code should _express intent_. The intent that calling `OfType<T>()` expresses is _"I want only objects that are type T"_. It's true that implies non-null only, but it's not the _reason_ for the method. _"What's the best way to filter them out?"_ -- a `where` clause is one way; an `if` statement in your loop is another; if you really want a method that does that, it's trivial to write your own `NotNull<T>()` method. You could even constrain it to `where T : class` for better expressiveness.